# How to install Grails plugins through Maven pom.xml?

Tags: java, grails, plugins, maven

I'm building a Grails project with Maven, which is the required way of building at my company.

On my local machine, I have installed a Grails plugin in the usual way `grails install-plugin foo`. Of course, when the project is built by Maven on the build server, it knows nothing about this plugin.

I've seen that the following can be useful for the case where the plugin is available in the plugins directory of Grails:

```
<plugin> 
  <groupId>org.grails</groupId> 
  <artifactId>grails-maven-plugin</artifactId> 
  <version>1.1</version> 
  <extensions>true</extensions> 
  <executions> 
    <execution> 
      <id>create plugins folder</id> 
      <phase>validate</phase> 
      <goals> 
        <goal>install-plugin</goal> 
      </goals> 
      <configuration> 
        <pluginUrl>${env.GRAILS_HOME}/plugins/grails-hibernate-1.1.zip</pluginUrl>                 
      </configuration> 
    </execution> 
  </executions>           
</plugin>
```

but suppose the plugin was not on the machine at all? What would the `pluginUrl` be in the case where Maven or Grails will need to go to the internet to find the plugin?

**Edit:**

I've found that the `pluginName` and `pluginVersion` tags are useful, and I've added the following execution to the `grails-maven-plugin`:

```
<execution>
  <id>Hibernate plugin</id>
  <phase>validate</phase>
  <goals>
    <goal>install-plugin</goal>
  </goals>
  <configuration>
    <pluginName>hibernate</pluginName>
    <pluginVersion>1.3.7</pluginVersion>
  </configuration>
</execution>
```

This *almost* works. If I check out my code in a new directory, and delete the contents of my plugins directories, Maven is able to build the project, successfully finding all plugin dependencies.

Yet it still doesn't work on the build server. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Try adding this dependency to your pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.grails.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>fields</artifactId>
    <version>1.3</version>
    <type>zip</type>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

when you recompile your App maven will download and install the plugin

Comment: Thanks @Cris! I don't imagine I'll return to this project for 2011 (at a different company) but this information might benefit someone else.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use Grails Maven plugin, so the pom will get updated with changes to the plugin list. Have a look at [Grails documentation describing Maven integration](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/4.%20The%20Command%20Line.html#4.5%20Ant%20and%20Maven), especially the section on "mavenizing" the project.

Comment: Are you saying to do `mvn org.grails:grails-maven-plugin:1.3.2:create-pom -DgroupId=com.mycompany`? That is how I originally obtained my pom.xml. Are you saying that this same command can be used to update the pom for Grails plugins?

Comment: No, grails plugin should pick up the newly installed plugins and add them to the build. Could you check if `application.properties` file is checked into the version control and whether it contains all the plugins that you need?

Comment: `application.properties` is checked in, and it does contain the name and version of all installed plugins.

Comment: I hate 'works for me' answers, but it should work even without manually specifying the plugins. So maybe you should check Maven installation on the build server? Maybe it's in different version or has something strange in ~/.m2/settings.xml?